# when I use the MNIST datasets,it has a mistake

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used the MNIST examples in tensorflow, a mistake indicates that

> No module named tensorflow.python.saved_model.model_utils

The code has only two sentences!

My os is windows, Tensorflow's version is `1.13.1`, it is installed by `pip` Python version is `3.7.2`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
```

The usage of this code is downloading the MNIST datasets.

Comment: Not reproducible with Python 3.6.8, tensorflow 1.12.0

Comment: And not reproducible with Python 3.7.2 and tensorflow 1.13.1

Comment: I don't understand ,what should I do? change python version or tensroflow

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the windows version, but I can't be sure because I don't have a Windows machine. Maybe removing and re-installing python/tensorflow will fix it, but not sure either.

Comment: I found this thread https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27079, I was not able to reproduce the error on tensorflow 1.4 and python 3.5. Hope it helps

Comment: What happens if you use tf.examples instead of tensorflow.examples?

Comment: uhhh.I solved this problem.I uninstalled Python3.7.2 and install the Python3.6.Thank your help!

Comment: Use `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()` instead